# Padding is part of a link

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, padding

I wrote html-code and I've got a problem. I added a link to an image, but this image has got a padding. So now the padding is part of the link as well as the image. Can I do something about it, so that only the image is linked ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Just testing</title>
        <style type=text/css>
            .design {background-color: orange; padding: 50px; border: thick double red; margin: 500}
            .design2 {background-color: yellow; padding: 10px 100px; border: thick groove red; margin: 10}
            .centered {text-align: center}
            #blink {text-decoration: underline overline;;color: red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: lightgray">
        <h1 class="centered design2">This is <span style="color:red">MY</span> site :D:D</h1>
        <a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Neugierige-Katze.JPG">
        <p class="centered"><img class="design" style="align: center" src="Neugierige-Katze.jpg" alt="tolle Katze" width="500" height="325">
        </p>
        </a>
        <p class="centered">Cat the Cat is <span id="blink"> WATCHING YOU</span>
        </p>
        <p class="centered">
            <audio controls>
                <source src="Cat_Meow_2-Cat_Stevens-2034822903.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                <source src="Cat_Meow_2-Cat_Stevens-2034822903.ogg" type="audio/ogg">

    </body>
</html>
```

I am grateful to anyone who can help me.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it http://jsbin.com/OdoSIme/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Just testing</title>
      <style type=text/css>
          .design {background-color: orange; padding: 50px; border: thick double red; margin: 500}
          .design2 {background-color: yellow; padding: 10px 100px; border: thick groove red; margin: 10}
          .centered {text-align: center}
          #blink {text-decoration: underline overline;color: red}
      </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: lightgray">
    <h1 class="centered design2">This is <span style="color:red">MY</span> site :D:D</h1>

    <p class="centered design" style="margin:0 auto; display: table;">
      <a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Neugierige-Katze.JPG">
        <img style="align: center" src="http://wallpapersfor.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cute_cat_praying-1280x800.jpg" alt="tolle Katze" width="500" height="325"> 
      </a>
    </p>

    <p class="centered">Cat the Cat is <span id="blink"> WATCHING YOU</span></p>
    <p class="centered">
        <audio controls>
            <source src="Cat_Meow_2-Cat_Stevens-2034822903.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
            <source src="Cat_Meow_2-Cat_Stevens-2034822903.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
        </audio>
  </body>
```

Comment: This works fine for me, but what does the atribute : style="margin:0 auto; display: table, actually stand for ?

Comment: It is a way of centering it since I gave it the `design` class. Otherwise it'd be on the left side

Comment: What difference  makes the auto value in the margin property ? And why do you use value 0 ?

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` is shorthand for `margin-top:0; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:auto;` or `margin: 0 auto 0 auto`. It removes the vertical margins and positions the element in the perfect center horizontally

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't put a block element like "p" into an inline elment like "a".
Why don't you put the "a" tag in the "p" tag?
Use margin instead of padding.

That's my result:

```
[...]
    <style type=text/css>
        .design {background-color: orange; margin: 50px; border: thick double red; margin: 500}
        .design2 {background-color: yellow; padding: 10px 100px; border: thick groove red; margin: 10}
        .centered {text-align: center}
        #blink {text-decoration: underline overline;;color: red}
    </style>
 [...]
    <p class="centered"> 

        <a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Neugierige-Katze.JPG" class="design"><img style="align: center" src="Neugierige-Katze.jpg" alt="tolle Katze" width="500" height="325"></a>

    </p>

   [...]
```

Works good for me

**edit**: Okay, margin is also possible. Just remove the span and put margin to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is considered a part of the element. If you don't want this behavior, use margin instead.